# Could not find bundletool-1.9.0.jar

Tags: flutter, gradle

When I run any project this error appears and when I sync gradle
I tried a lot of times to sync gradle but failed with this error
I upgraded Flutter SDK to the latest version.

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find bundletool-1.9.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.9.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/1.9.0/bundletool-1.9.0.jar

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

This is my gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```